# Why Abbyy FineReader Express is Corrupting View sometimes?

Tags: windows, macos, pdf, abbyy

I asked a year ago the the question from the support and they said that the problem is the Viewer.
When this kind of mistake happens by the software, the filesize normally gets 10X bigger.

Example:

[image]

The customer care claimed the View, but I think the software may have damaged Data.

Assume only View is damaged. **How can you fix it to show the entirepage?**
Rotation of the page does not help, tested in Windows, OSX and with different PDF Viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding an empty page in the beginning of the document and then doing the text-recognition again.